# iFrame reloading

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with two iframes - sidebar and content. The sidebar has links that targets the content iframe, so any links that are clicked on the sidebar will load on the content iframe.

I would like the sidebar to refresh whenever a page on the content iframe is loaded. What code would I need to add to the "content" pages to do this?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Providing they're in the same domain, you should be able to do something like this:

```
window
  .parent
    .document
      .getElementById('id_of_sidebar')
        .contentWindow
          .location
            .reload()
```

Written in a cascading style because that's the way I like it.  Feel free to put the whitespace wherever you like. :)

Disclaimer: I have not tested the above.

Comment: Thanks for the response.

I still can't quite get it to work though. Should I place this code in the body or maybe as an onload event?

Comment: The code is written from the perspective of the content iframe.  That is, this code assumes that it's being run from inside the content iframe window.  A better design would probably have code in the parent page which has an onload handler on the content iframe.  That handler would then calls location.reload() for the sidebar iframe.  There are several solutions to your problem, I just posted the first that came to mind.